# facebook ShareOpenGraph not working in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

i've followed documentation to share image + text on facebook , here is my code :

```
    ShareOpenGraphObject object = new ShareOpenGraphObject.Builder()
    .putString("og:type", "books.book")
    .putString("og:title", "A Game of Thrones")
    .putString("og:description", "In the frozen wastes to the north of Winterfell, sinister and supernatural forces are mustering.")
    .build();

ShareOpenGraphAction action = new ShareOpenGraphAction.Builder()
    .setActionType("books.reads")
    .putObject("book", object)
    .putPhoto("image", photo)
    .build();

ShareOpenGraphContent content = new ShareOpenGraphContent.Builder()
    .setPreviewPropertyName("book")
    .setAction(action)
    .build();
```

the sharing dialog is showing , and when i click on "post" it shows a progress Dialog and then nothing happens .

Comment: Recheck your app id and keyhashes.

Comment: i've done that , still nothing happens

Comment: The code seems ok. I have done this myself and it worked fine.